# decryption of message using private key

Tags: encryption, decryption, asymmetric, public-key

I don't why we can decrypt the message using our private key if it's encrypted using our public key.

If a message is encrypted using my public key, then how can I decrypt it using my private key? It doesn't make sense at all.

The only way it can do that is that on my side, the private key can be generated using my public key.

Can anybody make things clear for me?

Comment: You do know how keys are generated, right?

Comment: no; understanding the generation-process would clarify what i have asked?

Comment: It would help your understanding of how the process works. The keys are generated together at the same time.

Comment: There are numerous explainers out there for how all this works for non-technical people. Videos, blogs, infographics. I have linked our answers to your question above. Even wiki has a good overview.